# How to override a rails 3 template within a gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Rails 3 project where I override some scaffold templates.  This is done by placing a new template in lib/templates/erb/scaffold and adding lib to my autoload path in config/application.rb (see Rasilscasts #216).

Now, I'd like to package my work in a gem. (I'm new to gems...)

I cannot figure out how to accomplish this in a gem.

Looking at generators.rb I see there is a configuration for templates dir:

```
  templates_path.concat config.templates
  templates_path.uniq!
```

but I'm not sure how to use it.

I don't **think** I'm supposed to mess with the lib dir from a gem (or even if I *can* do that).

So my question is, how do I accomplish this from a gem?

Thanks in advance

jeff

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding `lib` to your `autoload_path` you add your gem's `lib` directory (though I think this should happen automatically). If you provide some code excerpts I can probably give more specific advice, though

Comment: ok I will (tomorrow), but (1) how does a gem modify the autoload path and (2) the gem's lib dir could be anywhere?  Is there a constant I should make use of?

Comment: actually I think it IS in my autoload path from my gemspec's require_paths command.  That I have verified.  But that does not appear to be how templates are loaded.

Comment: This is because autoload/require paths are for ruby files, not templates. There should be another variable (like view_paths or something) that you use instead.